# Почему-то не появляется модальное окно

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Эксперементировал вот по этому [гайду](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/14.6.php) с небольшими изменениями, но почему-то в итоге открывается новая страница, а не модальное окно.

В итоге у меня получилась вот такая разметка главной вьюхи:

```
<div id="modDialog" class="modal fade">
        <div id="dialogContent" class="modal-dialog"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table id="storageList" class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Storage_id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>TotalFreeSpace</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @{
                    foreach (var storage in Model)
                    {
                        <tr id="clickable"
                            onclick="location.href = '@(Url.Action("Details", null, new {storageId = storage.StorageId}))'">
                            <td id="storageId">@storage.StorageId</td>
                            <td id="name">@storage.Name</td>
                            <td id="totalFreeSpace">@storage.TotalFreeSpace</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            $('#clickable').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.get(this.href, function (data) {
                    $('#dialogContent').html(data);
                    $('#modDialog').modal('show');
                });
            });
        })
</script>
```

Такая разметка у частичного представления:

```
@model String

<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" area-hidden="true">X</button>
        <h4>@Model</h4>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            </dl>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Вот этот метод рисует частичное представление:

```
 public ActionResult Details(string storageId)
    {
        return PartialView(null,storageId);
    }
```

В логе браузера пишется:

> "[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is
>   deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's
>   experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/."

Подскажите, где я допустил ошибку?

**UPD**

Переписал скрипт в такой вид

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            $('#clickable').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var target = $(e.target);
                var link = "@(Url.Action("Details", null, new {storageId = "tmp"}))";
                link = link.replace("tmp", target.text());
                $.get(link, function (data) {
                    $("#dialogContent").html(data);
                    $("#modDialog").modal('show');
                });
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Теперь окно есть, но оно открывается только на первой строчке... Где еще может быть ошибка?

Comment: два обработчика на клик регистрируются - один в onclick, второй в $.ready, а открывает новую страницу, потому что location.href присваиваешь новое значение

Comment: какой смысл при подключенном jquery писать `onclick` посреди html кода, не понимаю.

Comment: @teran я новичок:). Можете привести пример в комментах, как это делается красивее?

Comment: @MikhailM, спасибо. А не подскажете, почему событие срабатывает только на первой строчке таблицы?

Comment: потому что id селектор используется (#), так как это идентификатор, то подразумевается что он должен быть единственный в DOM, если же их несколько, то выбирается первый попавшийся. Используй вместо этого класс _class="clickable"_ и селектор _.clickable_

Comment: @MikhailM спасибо. Работает